# "Add" button disabled for preferred locations in Job Match preferences

Tags: support

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask but when editing my Job Match preferences, I can't add any places. I could up until a couple of days ago, but now the button is disabled.

I even deleted most of the current places I had thinking that it had a limit, but it's still disabled and now I can't even add back the placed I had before.

Also, the autocomplete is not working so I'm guessing it might have to do with this issue.

Any ideas on what could be happening?

Edit:

Opened the console and found this error:

```
This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 187.xxx.xxx.xxx, with referer: https://maps.googleapis.com/ For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
```

in

`js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCFIp-QsebzlYof2EksHOALVtoM-xxxxxx:35`​

Edit 2:

Some more details:

Autocomplete works now, but the "Add" button is still disabled.

New error appears:

```
story.en.js?v=72843215e98d:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
    at jx.<anonymous> (story.en.js?v=72843215e98d:1)
    at Object._.z.trigger (js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCFIp-QsebzlYof2EksHOALVtoM-0SgkZQ:98)
    at Hb (js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCFIp-QsebzlYof2EksHOALVtoM-0SgkZQ:38)
    at Hb (js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCFIp-QsebzlYof2EksHOALVtoM-0SgkZQ:38)
```